# PHP url rewriting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

i am trying to make the URL in my PHP application cleaner using htaccess. Earlier the links of my application were in this format

`http://localhost/25_2_april/video.php?cat_id=2&category=Programming-Language`, but with the help of htaccess i was able to convert it into

`http://localhost/25_2_april/video-library/2/Programming-Language`. Now ,the question is that every time i run my application it loads the messy URL instead of the clean URL , although when i edit the url ,and make it clean url, then that works too. Now is there any way, that it directly loads the clean url instead of the messy url.

Below is the anchor tag through which i am calling this particular page.

`<a href="<?php echo 'video.php?cat_id='.$cat_id.'&category='.$cat_name; ?>">`

Comment: Could you please show your htaccess ? But you can also edit the link in order to looks like the new one.

Comment: `Options +FollowSymLinks`


`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
`RewriteRule ^video-library/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /var/www/html/25_2_april/video.php?cat_id=$1&category=$2  [L]`
`RewriteRule ^video-library/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /var/www/html/25_2_april/search_results.php?cat_id=$1  [L]`

Comment: @HarjeevSingh: you should make the opposite, put the clean url in the link href, and the htaccess will transform for the messy url

Comment: i tried this approach, it works , but when i click on another category displayed on that page . this link is created `http://localhost/25_2_april/video-library/2/Programming-Lang‌​uage/15/Java` , instead of `http://localhost/25_2_april/video-library/15/Java`

Comment: if you want to work with clean url, don't put the relative url, make it absolute url

Comment: Sound like a problem with relative URLs. To solve this you have to put an absolute URL, starting with `http` or `/`, in your `href`.

Comment: tried this `<?php echo '/video-library/'.$cat_id.'/'.$cat_name; ?>` , but now the url generated is `http://localhost/video-library/2/Programming-Language`.It skips the folder name i.e, `25_2_april` , hence it is not working. I am refraining to use `25_2_april` inside my code.

Comment: @HarjeevSingh try the absolute url like this "http://localhost/25_2_april/video-library/".$cat_id."/".$cat_name

Comment: but for that . i'd have to put this path everywhere in the code, and i am not sure if that would be the right approach, i mean when i host this code i'll have to again adjust the path according to my web server folder.

Comment: Also one more issue after this is , that my CSS and JS are not working, after htaccess . i know this again is related to the absolute path and relative path , but i can't seem to get my head around it.

Comment: you can make an constant BASE_URL = "http://localhost/" in one file config or the header.php which you will inlude in your files, and when you make the hebergement, you replace just this constant, another thing you can make BASE_URL  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/"

Comment: with my experience, the best way for development web, is the working with absolute url, for css and js also

Comment: can you show me an example where i could place this `BASE_URL` , i mean i dont have a config or a header.php , just basic files along with .htaccess.

Comment: I tried putting the localhost as the absolute path , in this format `<?php echo 'localhost/25_2_april/video-library/'.$cat_id.'/'.$cat_name; ?>` , but the resultant path is `http://localhost/25_2_april/video-library/1/localhost/25_2_april/video-library/2/Programming-Language`

Comment: isn't localhost but put the "http://" before localhost

Comment: @HarjeevSingh; for the BASE_URI, you can make it in the header of each file after <?php and you can use it after that

Answer (score 0):

As you are adding static URL in html so must have to pass your clean URL as :

```
<a href="<?php echo 'http://localhost/25_2_april/video-library/'.$cat_id.'/'.$cat_name; ">
```

Comment: i tried this approach, it works , but when i click on another category displayed on that page . this link is created `http://localhost/25_2_april/video-library/2/Programming-Language/15/Java` , instead of  `http://localhost/25_2_april/video-library/15/Java`